# Creating Database Using Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am just following an ASP.NET MVC 5 book and in chapter 13 we are deploying to Azure.
I have followed the instructions of the book but since the time book is written, things have changed in Azure UI.
**The book says:**

> "The next step is to create the schema for database: Click the Design
>   SQL database link in the Connect to your Database section, enter the
>   database name, user name, password and click the LogOn button"

But this is the screen shot I see in my Azure and can't find what he says in the book.

[image]

Comment: Well if you have SQL Server Management Studio installed, you can directly go there and type the servername, username and password and you can start creating DB there too. Kind of a different path leading to the same destination.

Comment: @MattMurdock I just want to follow the book steps so after this step at least be able to continue with the rest of it to deploy my app.

Comment: AFAIK, it wont affect the deployment part since this step only involves creating the schema of your DB which is something you can do quite easily from SQL Server Management studio. I use Azure and I do the same thing after creating a DB on Azure. I understand that things might have changed and if its only the schema part that you are concerned with, I would suggest you to proceed with this alternate way.

Comment: yeah it was easy, I didn't have SQL Server Management Studio at home installed, this morning tried it at work and was pretty easy to do from there. thanks.